# How to connecting Tableau to local MySQL db in Other Machine

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

I have MySQL DB on Localhost in my laptop. I can connect tableau to this DB on my laptop. 
My question is, I have Local MySQL DB in other laptop on same network. **How I can connect this DB to Tableau ?**

Thanks

Josu

Comment: Connect it the same way that you connected in on the primary laptop? I'm not sure I understand your question, is the difference that one DB is on localhost vs local?

Answer (score 1):

After you click on "Add New Data Source" in Tableau then choosing MySQL.
Put the server name of the other machine in the server section.